# How to prevent static instances of simple C++ class objects while allowing dynamic instances

Tags: c++

I know how to prevent dynamic instantiation of a class in C++. (Define my own 'new' operator) But is there a simple way to prevent static instantiation so that I force dynamic instances? That is, how do I do this... (This is not a derivable abstract base class. Just a simple class)

```
class B {

};

B b;  // how do I prevent this without using friends or some derived class trick

B* b;
b = new B;  // still want to be able to do this.
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this?

Answer (score 13):

You can prevent it by making the c'tor private:

```
class B {
B() {}

public:
  static B* alloc() { return new B; }
};
```

Instead of `b = new B;` you will do: `b = B::alloc();`

Comment: I think you mean `b = B::alloc();`

Answer (score 1):

> You can prevent it by making the c'tor private:
> `class B { ...
>   };`
>  Instead of `b = new B;` you will do: `b = B::alloc();`

But this is only half of the truth, right? I could still do an

`static B* b = B::alloc();`

yielding a pointer to a statically (i. e. created before execution of main()) object - i.e. this is more or less a static object, it only is located on the heap. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: If someone went to all that effort, I'm sure they know what they're doing and have a good reason for it.